# C# Selenium QA - how to extract the value of custom attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, extract, custom-tag

I have complex DOM structure with dynamically changing values of the HTML id attributes. Selenium is returning "null" when I attempt to extract the values of the "custom" attributes.

I need to extract the value of parentId (namely I need the "qqq-bbb", which is different on every reload)

```js
//Selenium(C#): 
// evaluates to "null"
string someStringName = someIWebElement.GetAttribute("parentId");
   

//HTML tag (example): 
// in Chrome the parentId is visible and unique
<g id="333-aaa" parentId="qqq-bbb">
```

Comment: Do you have a problem locating the element? or just extracting `parentId`?

Comment: Problem extracting the parentId value (the string I try assign the return value, in the example "someStringName" remains "null" after evaluation of the code

Comment: Make sure you are locating the correct element, maybe there are more elements with the same locator you used and you found one of them.

Comment: Try printing `someIWebElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML");` and see what the element looks like. My guess is that you don't have the element you are expecting.

Comment: No, the element is unique. It has an id, that corresponds to the cirrent element id value (visually verified in the Chrome f12 console), however element cannot be helpful to locate the element, as during the next reload the id will be different - dynamically allocated per session)... and yes, the HTML tag is the <g> ,i.e the outermost tag of the selected IWebElement.... must be sth connected to the visibility of the "custom" tahs (just gessing now, but continue the investigatin). Any known workarounds, ideas or tricks will be appreciated

Comment: Clarification: element id, used in the selection, is unique...

Answer (score 0):

Solution: (based on recommendation in comment#2). Issuing the following command returns as string the contents of the tag AND by applying the right parse you get the attribute value you need

```js
string outerHTML = foundIWebElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML");
```