# Assert attribute value contrains specifict string

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to assert that when selecting a tab from https://demoqa.com/tabs/ the selected tab contains `aria-selected="true"`.

```
var attributeValue = tabsPage.SecondTab.GetAttribute("aria-selected");
Assert.AreEqual(attributeValue, "true");
```

doesn't seem to work.

When debugging `attributeValue` is `null`

Comment: According to the documentation for [GetAttribute](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm), that method "Returns a null if the value is not set". Are you certain you've selected the correct element? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249226/c-sharp-selenium-qa-how-to-extract-the-value-of-custom-attribute) describes how that can be verified if you're unsure

Comment: Yep, changing the elment solved the problem.